# LSUIElement not working

Tags: macos, cocoa, info.plist, lsuielement

I have an application that has LSUIElement = 1 in the Info.plist. When I run the application, a dock item and toplevel menu bar is created for it. Why?

EDIT:

I was using a library that was calling TransformProcessType(), clobbering my Info.plist configuration.

Comment: Can you post the app somewhere, or at least your Info.plist?  And please, learn how to ask questions.

Comment: i thought you're question was just fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to your Info.plist file, and add a new key-value pair, or type Boolean.  Start typing in the key the phrase "Application is agent".  It should auto-complete for you.  Then check the checkbox.

This is how I create my agent applications, and it works every time!

Comment: It is a string (not a boolean) according to this Apple page: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html

Answer (score 4):

The 1 must be a string, not a number (according to [the documentation of `LSUIElement`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256)).  Something to try anyway.

Comment: Correct, according to this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html