# Java OS X - No app icon in dock

Tags: java, macos, info.plist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LSUIElement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762456/lsuielement-not-working)

I am using Jar Bundler to create a .app file out of my .jar file. When I launch the app, I do not want a dock icon to show at all.

I have already tried modifying my .plist file to include:

```
<string>NSUIElement</string>
<key>1</key>
```

But it does not work... Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your tags are backwards.

```
<key>NSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

You may also try:

```
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<string>1</string>
```

Comment: Using Property List Editor to edit the plist helps you avoid a lot of mistakes like this.